# spacing issue between two html tag having bootstrap file in it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0pRj.jpg)I am using bootsteap 5 in screen shot h5 in black border and em tag in red border i spacify margin 0 to h5 but it still not touch to em tag (in red border), i had tried everything linespceing etc, but still both have space between them, here is my html structure.

```
<div class="mediaCard">
<img src="images/architectgirl-1.jpg" class="img-fluid">`
<h5>What value does a good Architect bring in my project? </h5>
<em>15 min read</em>
</div>
```

i try to to remove space between both the element and reset the spacing to default in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

That's probably due to the default padding or margin of the elements. Try changing the bottom padding of `h5` or the top padding of `em`.

Comment: already tried but did not work

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you are loading bootstrap styles after your own so the margin values with same specificity aren't taking precedence. Here is an example of loading styles in correct order to achieve the desired outcome:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  h5 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  em {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>

<div class="mediaCard">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="img-fluid">`
  <h5>What value does a good Architect bring in my project? </h5>
  <em>15 min read</em>
</div>
```

Comment: no, i had loaded my css files after the bootstrap, this is matter is not realated to file precedence

Comment: @RajeshVaishnav then please share your entire code as there must be something additional interfering, as you can see an isolated reproduction in my answer does not have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

by giving display block property to em my problem is resolved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).